# Android custom view background covering view content

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I'm trying to figure out why an Android custom view which works when no background is set suddenly stops working when the background is set. It seems the background covers the items added to the view when it is set. I've simplified the view code to the bare minimum which reproduces the problem and to be able to post the code here. The custom view inherits from `RelativeLayout` and the code is as follow:

```
public class TestView extends RelativeLayout {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ViewTreeObserver mViewTreeObserber;
    private boolean mInitialized = false;

    public TestView(Context ctx) {
        super(ctx, null);
        initialize(ctx, null, 0);
    }
    public TestView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(ctx, attrs);
        initialize(ctx, attrs, 0);
    }
    public TestView(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(ctx, attrs, defStyle);
        initialize(ctx, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    private void initialize(Context ctx, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mViewTreeObserber = getViewTreeObserver();
        mViewTreeObserber.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                if (!mInitialized) {
                    mInitialized = true;
                    drawItem();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        drawItem();
    }
    private void drawItem() {
        if (!mInitialized) return;
        removeAllViews();
        View item = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.testview_item, null);
        TextView txt = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.test_view_item);
        txt.setText("Test View Text");
        txt.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        txt.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 12);
        addView(item);
    }
}
```

The item layout is simple:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test_view_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And the sample app simply declares two instances of the custom view in XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView android:text="With Background set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.machado.felipe.TestView
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.machado.felipe.TestView>
    <TextView android:text="WithOUT Background set"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <com.machado.felipe.TestView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </com.machado.felipe.TestView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The result looks like the picture bellow:

[image]

This is driving me crazy! I'm not used to write custom views in android and this is someone else's code which I'm trying to fix! I don't even know if this is the way it should be done, since I'm inflating views and adding them to the RelativeLayout I don't think I should be adding them in the onDraw, but since the complete code is doing more complex stuff, as laying out the items in multiple rows with wrapping, it is possibly a valid approach... But, anyway, I can't figure out how to fix this!

Comment: what do you need `onGlobalLayout` and `drawItem` for?

Comment: @pskink I haven't the slightest idea! This is not my code... I'm just trying to fix it! The original code does a lot of other stuff. It is a Tag View library: https://github.com/Cutta/TagView It measures the width so that the layout params are on the view are set to correctly "wrap" when it does not fit horizontally besides other items. I've just stripped all that code to reproduce the problem. You can see the complete code here: https://github.com/Cutta/TagView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/cunoraz/tagview/TagView.java

Comment: I'm suggesting you to rewrite this code, cause is sooo bad... `drawItem` method gets so much hits (+never unregistered `ViewTreeObserver`) and inflater have so much work to do  that I can only guess you have here smth like "drawing race"...

Comment: I understand you're just trying to use the library, but I have to agree with @snachmsm the code on this library is HORRIBLE. It's an absolute crap abysmal performance hog. This onGlobalLayout initialisation demonstrates a total lack of understanding for the View measure cycle. The drawTags inside the onDraw creates an infinite post look on the main thread and overloads the garbage collector in really bad ways. My suggestion, find other library, that one is crap!

Comment: so this is lib... do you have access to code? or you may want to import (make a branch?) this lib and try to add `TextView` straight inside `initialize(...)` by own... it's very unproper way for adding new `View`, probably causes heavy drawing-loop: every `addView`/`removeAllViews` obviously causes `onDraw` calls (parent change), which are again clearing all, adding new... also `GlobalLayoutListener` is called probably in most of iterations of this loop causing... second loop. have you investigated proc/ram usage?

Comment: @snachmsm I've already forked the lib on github. I'm was trying to "fix" it but now I see that the problem is "deeper". I'll study a little about custom views and will try to rewrite it on my own. Or, maybe, I'll just use FlowLayout from google and add custom tags there. The original code: https://github.com/Cutta/TagView/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/cunoraz/tagview/TagView.java

Comment: if you have any alternative from Google I say: go this way! good luck :)